# Clean url in index view file in YII

Tags: php, yii

In my index view file i have:

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.CListView', array(
'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
'itemView'=>'_view',
'ajaxUpdate'=>false,
));
```

A have a lot of records so the pagination appears. The problem is when i go to second page /actor/index?Actor_page=2. I need a way to format this url into a more friendly one, for example: /actor/page/2. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this topic on [yii url management](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.url), I guess what you need can be achieved with `'urlFormat'=>'path',`

Answer (score 0):

Break up your uri into segemnts explode('/', uri), then check for int or string..

remove base uri from segment and assign[0][1][2] to certain segments in your framework